# AWS CloudFormation not honouring implicit dependencies

Tags: dependencies, aws-cloudformation

Using CloudFormation I have created an EC2 instance with an attached EBS volume. While the create works just fine, the delete always fails because CloudFormation tries to delete the EBS volume before the EC2 instance, so predictably an error occurs.

> Volume vol-xxxxxx is currently attached to i-xxxxxx

In the template, there is no explicit dependency, but my understanding is that dependencies can also be implicit. As you can see from the snippet below, the `VolumeId` specified for the EC2 instance is `!Ref SasEbsVolume`, thus the dependency is implied, and the EC2 instance should be deleted before the EBS volume.

```
Resources:
  SasEbsVolume:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Volume
    DeletionPolicy: Snapshot
    Properties:
      ...

  SasInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ...
      Volumes:
        - Device: /dev/xvdd
          VolumeId: !Ref SasEbsVolume
```

So is my understanding of how dependencies in CloudFormation work incorrect, in which case I can declare an explicit dependency, or is CloudFormation not doing what it's supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was EC2 instance termination protection.

```
  SasInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ...
      DisableApiTermination: true
      ...
```

After removing termination protection, deletion of the CloudFormation template was successful.

Hopefully AWS make it obvious through CloudFormation events when this issue occurs, as currently nothing is in there to guide users at all.